# Example of "Disk not ejected properly" But Disk Drops Off System Entirely

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

I'm stuck in a loop with this issue on Ventura 13.2.1 and I've tried all the general suggestions in articles like [this](https://www.howtoisolve.com/fix-disk-not-ejected-properly-error-on-mac/).

The issue is the disk doesn't stay connected. So I can't reformat or run any first aid. If I reboot, it starts up and immediately shows the error and the disk drops off.

I know it's working as for a short period the disk is connected and I can see the exected files on it.

Accessing it just errors saying I'm not the owner and then prompty drops off the system and flashes up the not ejected error.

Really not sure what to try next.

Not sure how this issue started as the external drive is in a hub under the mac mini and it's never disconnected.

Comment: Is this a USB flash or drive?  Internal?  If so, which Mac model?

Comment: Sou ads like a problem with the disk. If it does similar things on another computer (Mac or PC, doesn't matter) then the drive may be defective.

Comment: Conversely, it could be the electronics in the drive case (external drive) at fault. If you can switch out with a new case (OWC has plenty of options) you may find the drive itself is fine. If this is a USB key, then all bets are off. Most USB thumb drives are best considered ephemeral storage media, and should not be trusted for long-term storage of unique and/or priceless data.